# BASH script echo text and a command

Tags: bash, echo, stderr

This is seriously lame I know but...Im pulling my hair out on it.

Basically I Have this code:

```
getDisplayName(){
echo Display Name: $(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice  -n)
}
```

It returns this:

```
[E] No device present
Display Name:
```

I would expect it to be:

```
Display Name: [E] No Device Present
```

What am I missing?

TIA Ron

Comment: The error message is being sent to standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty much like the error message from `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice` goes to the standard error stream (not standard output), so it is not captured by `$()`. Try redirecting to standard output using <strike>`2&>1`</strike> `2>&1`

```
getDisplayName(){
  echo Display Name: $(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice  -n 2>&1)
}
```

Comment: This creates a file with name `1`. I suggest to use `2>&1`.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, absolutely, thank you. Fxied the awnser.